# Python: how can I initialize my empty objects?

Tags: python, object, initialization, member

how can initialize empty objects in python ?

I need to initialize my class members (for examples tk.frames, vtk visualizations etc)

thanks

Comment: refer the online documentation: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/

Comment: -1: No Code.  Please **update** the question to include actual code that shows your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the attributes of `self` in your `__init__()` method.

```
class C(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
```

Comment: So, I don't need to add members to the class.. just declare them inside the constructor for the first time

Comment: Members added to the class directly become class attributes, and are shared across all instances of the class. This is rarely what is wanted for attributes other than methods.